# Iteration program

Tags: c, loops, iteration

I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* max_number.c: outputs the largest number of five numbers entered */

void main(void) {
  int i, num, max;

  for (i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    if (num >= max)
      max = num;
  }
  printf("The maximum number is %d\n", max);
}
```

When I run the program with any type of data I continually get "The maximum number is 14".  Can someone please point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong?  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Variable `max` is not initialized.

Try

```
int i, num, max = INT_MIN;
```

Comment: Exactly. The 14 must come from somewhere deterministic, but it is the uninitialized value.

Comment: Interesting.  Why would not initializing max to a value cause the program to give me that kind of output?  Thank you!

Comment: @user3727648 Uninitialized variable still has some value. I would not be surprised if `max` just happens to have value `14` in your case. And if all you input is less or equal to `14`, then it is the final result.

Comment: Thank you all for your help and explanation.